# How to Create Page Header with customized underline

Tags: html, css

I am trying to find creative ways to do page-headers, because the typical ones are boring, in my opinion.

Here is what I found:

[image]

Are those two separated `<hr />` elements with a `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star></span>` in between?

I have tried but can't figure out how to do it so that it is dynamic.  I don't want to have to adjust the css if the `<h1>` is longer than About (in the pic).

Here is what I have:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="text-center">About</h1>
  <hr class="new-hr" />
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
  <hr class="new-hr"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.new-hr{
  width: 20%
}
```

I have also created a [codepen](http://codepen.io/Bvillekid12/pen/PppRKv).

Can someone help me recreate this?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

Put a `div` with a bottom border, and the set the span containing the star to position:relative and move it down over the div.

```css
body {background: #fff;}
.underline {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.underline span {
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: #fff;
  font-size:25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="underline">
  <span>
    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first create `h1` element with `span` that will have star inside it. And to add lines you can use `:after` and `:before` pseudo-elements on `span`

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 10px 35px;
}
h1 > span {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
span:after, span:before {
  content: '';
  background: black;
  height: 1px;
  flex: 0 0 60%;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1>ABOUT<span>★</span></h1><br>
<h1>LOREM IPSUM<span>★</span></h1>
```

You can also do this without `Flexbox` using `position: absolute` to position pseudo-elements.

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 35px;
  display: inline-block;
}
h1 > span {
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
span:after, span:before {
  content: '';
  background: black;
  height: 1px;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
span:before {
  left: -15px;
}
span:after {
  right: -15px;
}
```

```html
<h1>ABOUT<span>★</span></h1><br>
<h1>LOREM IPSUM<span>★</span></h1>
```

Comment: Where did you find that star?

Comment: That is HTML special char, you can find lot of lists on google.

Comment: The `h1` element isn't centered over the span element for me

Comment: it also isn't centered on my page

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid Maybe take i look at update i think that should be it.

Answer (score 0):

You could give the heading a border, then add the star as a pseudoelement and position it in the center of the border...

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgreen !important;
}

.border {
  display: table;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #FFF;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.border::after {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings";
  content: "\e006";
  width: 28px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -18px;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  background: lightgreen;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="text-center border">About</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something exactly like this for the KTSW radio station ([demo](http://www.umarketing.txstate.edu/ktsw-demo)) using an `hr`, `hr::after` and a background image.

[Here is a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tsanzer/7fcjLhLf/) and an embedded example below.

```css
body {
    background: white;
}

hr {
    background: #ebebeb;
    margin: 5rem 0;
    position: initial;
    margin: 2rem 0;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0px solid #fff;
}

hr:after {
    background: url(http://txstate.edu/prospectiveflash/ktsw/boombox-hr.jpg) no-repeat top center;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    background-size: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="separator">
    <hr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is the best approach, but this should work.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class ="text-center">
        <h1 class="text">About</h1>
        <div class="icon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


.text-center{
    background: #6DD286;
    padding: 1px 10px 10px;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}
.text {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.icon {
    background: #6DD286;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    padding: 0 5px;
}
```